# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'subTree')

Tags: vue.js

Totally new to `Vue.js`. Here's my issue:-

```
<template>
    <div class="login-page">
        <transition name="fade">
            <div v-if="!registerActive" class="wallpaper-login"></div>
        </transition>
        <div class="wallpaper-register"></div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 mx-auto">
                    <div v-if="!registerActive" class="card login" v-bind:class="{ error: emptyFields }">
                        <h1>Sign In</h1>
                        <form class="form-group">
                            <input v-model="emailLogin" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                            <input v-model="passwordLogin" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="doLogin">
                            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="#" @click="registerActive = !registerActive, emptyFields = false">Sign up here</a>
                            </p>
                            <p><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div v-else class="card register" v-bind:class="{ error: emptyFields }">
                        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                        <form class="form-group">
                            <input v-model="emailReg" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                            <input v-model="passwordReg" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <input v-model="confirmReg" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="doRegister">
                            <p>Already have an account? <a href="#" @click="registerActive = !registerActive, emptyFields = false">Sign in here</a>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            registerActive: false,
            emailLogin: "",
            passwordLogin: "",
            emailReg: "",
            passwordReg: "",
            confirmReg: "",
            emptyFields: false
        };
    },
    methods: {
        doLogin() {
            if (this.emailLogin === "" || this.passwordLogin === "") {
                this.emptyFields = true;
            } else {
                alert("You are now logged in");
            }
        },

        doRegister() {
            if (this.emailReg === "" || this.passwordReg === "" || this.confirmReg === "") {
                this.emptyFields = true;
            } else {
                alert("You are now registered");
            }
        }
    }
};

</script>
```

My intentions are to wire-up the above to an API like thus:-

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login`

using either the fetch API or something similar. Currently, the form doesn't display in the browser and throws the above error..

[image]

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

With this, my `vue` `HTML` finally loads.

Remove these:-

**resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php**

```
{{--<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>--}}
{{--<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>--}}
</body>
</html>
```

Add this to your main file:-

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```

`npm run dev` and voila! Thanks to: [Murad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10461328/murad) for a very useful comment: [Vue3 Presence of a css class on element in single file component causes rendering failure when added to dom, Invalid VNode type: Symbol()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64161830/vue3-presence-of-a-css-class-on-element-in-single-file-component-causes-renderin)