# How I can render a component from a string with vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying render a component from string but I didn't succeed. My codes are bellow:

```
<template>
<div v-html="beautifyNotification(notification)"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import {compile,h} from "vue"

export default {
    components: {
    },
    props: {
        notifications: Object
    },
    methods: {
        beautifyNotification (ntfction) {
            return h(compile(`<Link :href="`+ntfction.from.username+`"
                    class="h6 notification-friend">`+ntfction.from.name+`
            </Link>, commented on your new
            <Link href="#" class="notification-link">profile status</Link>.`))
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I tried render component with h and compile but it returned `object object`

Comment: I don't see why you need to render your components like that in your example. Just use the `<Link />` inside the template. That's exactly how the components are supposed to be used 99% of the time.

Comment: Check out how `<todo-item />` is used in the docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#composing-with-components

Comment: Actually i want to learn how to render a string but if I don't find a solution I'll do like what you said

Comment: if you want to render an HTML string (literally a `"<div>This is a string HTML</div>"`) then you use `v-html`. Docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#raw-html

Answer (score 4):

To anyone else hopefully finding this, so you don't have to go down the hellish path of wrong answers that I did (very surprisingly no one's SO answers work properly, even though they specify vue 3). Even within the 'advanced' area of vue discord i was getting weird/wrong answers, which was surprsing.

The answer above by maembe didn't work for me either (it doesnt have access to any other components/scope)

This is what worked perfect for me.

Heres mine `CompiledContent` component that accepts html + vue components mixed together in a single string from backend.

Notice it doesn't use the `compile` function at all

```
<script>
import { h } from 'vue';
import AppAlert from '@/components/AppAlert.vue';

export default {
  props: {
    content: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  render() {
    const r = {
      components: {
        AppAlert,
      },
      template: `<div class="content">${this.content || ''}</div>`,
      methods: {
        hello() {
          // method "hello" is also available here
        },
      },
    };
    return h(r);
  },
};
</script>
```

If you have tons of components in your content you can also make them all async components:

```
components: {
  AppAlert: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/AppAlert.vue')), 
  ...
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to render anything for me, nothing in the DOM, but the component does exist in the Vue component tree with all the correct props/computed, the render code for it is am empty function.... The content of your `AppAlert` may be important here no?

Comment: Just more strings of answers that don't appear work without enough explanation in them to understand what they are trying to do in the first place :(

Comment: So, for this to work you need to have runtime compilation enabled, this method of compilation shows no console errors, it just fails silently and renders an empty comment otherwise. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74305016/3547347

Comment: This causes performance problems. We should consider alternatives like using vue's low-level APIs or a simple template compiler.

Comment: @TachibanaShin you're welcome to add another answer instead of just saying it's un-ideal. I have spent hours and hours in discord with all top level Vue people who still didn't give working answers. I'm open to seeing a better way, but nothing else actually worked, or people didn't know

Comment: @Tallboy I answered a similar question on stackoverflow people didn't see it because they actually didn't seem to be looking for it

Comment: @Tallboy I added an answer that uses the basic compiler method

Comment: Nice, if you had that answer elsewhere on SO I didnt see it, I looked for quite awhile. Can you link me to the other question where you answered it?

Comment: Thanks @Tallboy - you've done the lords work. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I will answer this question even though it seems late
Below I use the static compilation method

### Advantage:

- Fast and less CPU intensive: it uses native compilation instead of bundling the entire heavy vue compiler into your package
- Saves memory: This method only uses vue's prototype functions instead of including the compiler so it doesn't consume any memory

### Defect:

- Does not support SFC syntax: this is a native compiler so it will not accept regular `{{ value }}` (although you can add one) but it reluctantly supports event  `syntax @click=...` and compopnent prop support

```
import { Fragment, h, Component, defineComponent } from "vue"

function buildElement(element: ChildNode, components: Record<string, Component>) {
  if (element.nodeType === 1) {
    const { attributes } = element as HTMLElement

    const name = element.nodeName
    const attrs: Record<string, unknown> = {}
    for (let index = 0; index < attributes.length; index++) {
      const attr = attributes.item(index)
      attrs[attr.name] = attr.value
    }

    const children = compilerChildren(element as HTMLElement, components)

    const component = components[element.nodeName.toLowerCase()]
    console.log(element.nodeName, components)

    return component ? h(component, attrs, {
      default: () => children
    }) : h(name, attrs, children)
    // console.log({ name, attrs, children })
  }

  return element.textContent
}

function compilerChildren(parent: HTMLElement, components: Record<string, Component>) {
  // deflag
  const children = []
  parent.childNodes.forEach(item => {
    switch (item.nodeType) {
      case 1:
      case 3:
        // normal element
        children.push(buildElement(item, components))
        break
      default:
        console.warn("Can't resolve this element: ", item)
    }
  })

  return children
}


export function compiler(html: string, components: Record<string, Component>) {
  const comps = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(components).map(([name, component]) => [name.toLowerCase(), component])
  )
  return () => h(Fragment, null, compilerChildren(
    new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html").body,
    comps
  ))
}
```

> Here is the common version so people who don't have in-depth knowledge of vue's low-level APIs can understand I would normally use `openBlock`

Demo:

[image]

https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: The DOMParser() works well when navigating from another screen to the one where things are rendered using a compiler. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected when refreshing the page or directly accessing the page through the URL.

Comment: @AdityaPrasadDhal What are you having problems with?

Comment: got the issue @TachibanaShin. I am using it in nuxt and DOMParser doesn't work in server side. So, I am currently using it only in the client side. Utterly grateful for your help.

Comment: @AdityaPrasadDhal don't use `domparser` it's an unforgiving API use `cheerio` or `htmlparser2`.  If you cannot solve the problem. Please create a new question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You're using the h function wrong here.  h() returns virtual node that is meant to be used inside a render() function instead of a template.  You don't need a <template> or <v-html> at all in this case:

```
//no template element
<script>
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import {compile,h} from "vue"

export default {
    props: {
        notifications: Object
    },
    render() {
        return h(
           // abbreviated template string for brevity
           compile('<Link href="#" class="notification-link">profile status</Link>')
        ) 
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I wonder about can I use a specific function that I call later under render()

Comment: what do you mean by that?  render() is just a function, so you can call other functions from within it

Comment: my `compile` always return `undefined`. is it correct?

Comment: try wrapping the whole thing in a div

Comment: Ive tried importing it but i still get `Failed to resolve component`