# Vue 3 - Render component from string

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api, vue-props, vuejs-slots

I have a question. I have a component called ValidateCheckboxes. ValidateCheckboxes is a validated list of checkboxes. I pass checkboxes to this component by props. It look like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4qqP.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40IXT.png)
I am displaying checkboxes using v-for:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp3ne.png)
but my label look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPKmZ.png)

How to render custom component from string? Or maybe should I use another way to do that?
It's my first question, thanks for answers. :)

I tried use v-html but it didn't work.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . Proceed from the fact that you shouldn't do this, as this makes it much more complicated then it should be. In such cases the slots are usually used

Comment: Okay, thanks. So should I use slots and avoid using v-for in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should use slots, as they provide more control.
If you absolutely can't do that because stuff is loaded from a file, database or otherwise fetched from API - you can look into `h()` and `compile()` - [How I can render a component from a string with vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70957780/how-i-can-render-a-component-from-a-string-with-vue-3)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: @DouglasGaskell That's a valid point.