How to make in-DOM vue templates work with typescript?
I would like to create a vue app with an in-DOM template. However, typescript complains about it in my IDE (VSCodium). What shall I do to make it stop throwing that error?
Typescript error in IDE: Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
If the 'vue' package actually exposes this module, try adding a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';ts(7016)
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'

In fact, vue does have a file 'vue/dist/vue.d.ts', why doesn't TS detect it?
The only thing that fails is TS in my IDE, but not JS, which is working fine.

Map vue package to vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler in vite settings

How can I do that? @EstusFlask

Now I have a different error, as I added .js format at import.

This isn't what dupe question suggests. Can you clarify what the current attempt looks like? There's supposed to be alias in vite config https://stackoverflow.com/a/74305016/3731501 , vue.esm-bundler shouldn't be mentioned anywhere else in the project

Sure, I have edited the question with the new error. I may not need the alias as in my new error typescript does find the file.

You aren't supposed to import .js file in TS, unless it has .d.ts to match, and vue.esm-bundler.js doesn't. You'll need custom typings for it, this is another task. it can be avoided

Thanks @EstusFlask . The alias started working when I restarted my IDE.
